# Convert custom markdown to HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, handlebars.js, markdown

**Challenge :** Our users have access to an "contentEditable" DIV in which a JS library inserts HTML in it. Here's how we thought the HTML should show up in the contentEditable :

```
<span class="stylish-blue-button">

   <span style="display:none;">[data-user="12345" data-userId="678910"]</span>

     John Smith

   <span style="display:none;">[/]</span>

</span>

...Blablabla some other text...
```

We hand over this HTML to PHP, where we execute strip_tags(). This should give us :

```
[data-user="12345" data-userId="678910"]John Smith[/] ...Blablabla some other text...
```

**Question :** When rendering the text on the page, we were wondering if there was a secure/reliable way to have the above custom markdown converted to (before handing it to Handlebars.js) :

```
<span class="stylish-blue-button" data-user="12345" data-userId="678910">John Smith</span> ...Blablabla some other text...
```

**Why :** This assures us that the user generated content was handled safely, all while keeping the user generated markdown in the contentEditable "pretty" ("stylish-blue-button" class).

If you have any suggestions to make this whole process simpler, we're opened to changing our markdown's format.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You could use a regex; is that format consistent?

Comment: I think HTML parsing is the preferred approach over regexing HTML. Since you are stripping the elements I think a regex would suffice. I've posted an answer below demonstrating an approach you could take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
$string = '<span class="stylish-blue-button">

   <span style="display:none;">[data-user="12345" data-userId="678910"]</span>

     John Smith

   <span style="display:none;">[/]</span>

</span>

...Blablabla some other text...';
echo preg_replace('~\[(data-user="\d+")\h+(data-userId="\d+")\]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/\]\s*(.*)~s', '<span $1 $2>$3</span>$4', trim(strip_tags($string)));
```

Here's a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK1cL5/1) explaining exactly what that regex is doing. If you have a particular questions please ask.

Output:

```
<span data-user="12345" data-userId="678910">John Smith</span>...Blablabla some other text...
```

A few quick regex notes.

`*` is a quantifier meaning zero or more of the preceding character.
`+` is a quantifier meaning one or more (aka it is required) of the preceding character.
`\s` is a whitespace character.
`\h` is a horizontal space.
`.` is any single character.
`\d` is a single number (0-9).
`()` are capturing groups they capture into `$1`, `$2` etc. in the order they were found.

Looking at that regex again a quick note: This `\[/\]` is read as literal `[/]`. The backslashes are escaping the `[]` which otherwise would create a character class (meaning only the `/` character would be allowed there).

Multi-instances:

```
$string = '<span class="stylish-blue-button">

   <span style="display:none;">[data-user="12345" data-userId="678910"]</span>

     John Smith

   <span style="display:none;">[/]</span>

</span>

...Blablabla some other text...
<span class="stylish-blue-button">

   <span style="display:none;">[data-user="12345" data-userId="678910"]</span>

     John Smith

   <span style="display:none;">[/]</span>

</span>

...Blablabla some other text...
<span class="stylish-blue-button">

   <span style="display:none;">[data-user="12345" data-userId="678910"]</span>

     John Smith

   <span style="display:none;">[/]</span>

</span>

...Blablabla some other text...';
echo preg_replace('~\s*\[(data-user="\d+")\h+(data-userId="\d+")\]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/\]\s*~s', '<span $1 $2>$3</span>', trim(strip_tags($string)));
```

Output:

```
<span data-user="12345" data-userId="678910">John Smith</span>...Blablabla some other text...<span data-user="12345" data-userId="678910">John Smith</span>...Blablabla some other text...<span data-user="12345" data-userId="678910">John Smith</span>...Blablabla some other text...
```

For looser Ids just change the `\d+` to `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+`.

So:

```
preg_replace('~\s*\[(data-user="\d+")\h+(data-userId="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+")\]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/\]\s*~s'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm extremely grateful. I knew about a few regex websites, but this one looks fantastic. I will try your suggestion  ASAP and keep you posted. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for your edits. I'm trying a few things already and putting this approach through rigorous testing. I knew about escaping and capturing, but you've definitely taught me a lot already. Thank you.

Comment: I was wondering; how would I go if I had to replace multiple instances of my custom markdown ("[data-user=29353"...][/]"). It seems like your suggestion only replaces one. I've just done a lot of research, and it seems like preg_replace_callback() is my only option, but my tests have failed me. Thank you again.

Comment: That is because the last `(.*)` is capturing everything after the closing `[/]`, don't actually need that though because it will only replace the bit it finds. My mistake, or rather over complicating.

Comment: Any other questions/issues with this? Looks like you have two other questions with accepted answers that were from this answer.

Comment: Here is my attempt : '~\[(data-userNameReplyTo="[\s*(.+?)\s*\]+")\s+(data-userIdReplyTo="[\d-]+")\]\s*(.+?)\s*\[\/\]\s*(.*)~is'

Comment: So the `\d+` is number. Just change that to `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+` which will allow one or many number, letter, or space. That, `[]` is a character class which lists allowed characters and ranges of characters. Updated answer with a usage example..

Comment: Ah! Thanks a million Christ. Funny thing is I knew about "[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" very well, I guess I was too narrow-minded on what you typed down. Thanks again, this has helped me tons. I'm all set.

Comment: Think of character class as one large grouping of characters/ranges. They say `this` or `this` or `this` etc. and with the quantifier they may occur more than once. Without the quantifier only one of them is expected/allowed.

Comment: I think they are less used because when they go wrong they usually go very wrong. Anything else needed for this to be accepted?